# BeanWrapperFieldsetMapper mapping PropertyEditor per field basis

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch for file to database processing and currently I'm using [PropertyEditors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/package-summary.html) to convert strings in delimited file to some object as provided below.

```
Map<Class<?>, PropertyEditor> editors = new HashMap<>();
CustomDateEditor dateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), true);
editors.put(Date.class, dateEditor);
```

So if I have a Date field I am using [CustomDateEditor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomDateEditor.html) and its successfully parsing the given format date string. However if I have few more date strings in the same file with different formatting, I'm unable to parse them. What I need is to associate the editors to fields, so is there a way I could do that?

Comment: AFAIK spring batch internally registers Custom Editors from Map<Class<?>, PropertyEditors> while creating DataBinder which binds the class provided in map to the target object fields. So I don't see any option to do what you're saying.

Comment: As provided above in the question, I'm already using SimpleDateFormat in CustomDateEditor, so there is no need for a new Formatter, its not really about the date format, its about how can I support multiple formats.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @James Sorry, I couldn't find a way to do so. I had to stick with a specific date format for the file.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you want two distinct columns to have distinct date formats (not different rows to have different formats). You can do that by implementing a FieldSetMapper, as stated in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html).

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> secondReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data2.csv"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName", "fDate", "sDate" });
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(new PersonMapper());
        }
    });
    return reader;
}
```

implementation:

```
public class PersonMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Person> {

@Override
public Person mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName(fieldSet.readString("firstName"));
    person.setLastName(fieldSet.readString("lastName"));
    person.setFirstDate(fieldSet.readDate("fDate", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
    person.setSecondDate(fieldSet.readDate("sDate", "dd-MMM-yyyy"));
    return person;
}
```

}